# add arrow icon next to read more link on latest posts gutenberg block

Tags: block-editor

I want to add arrow next to read more link. Tried to edit latest-posts.php but didn't manage to work it out.
[image]

Comment: You can just do it through CSS using the `:after` pseudo selector.  Can't offer much more than that because you've only included a picture. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14695403/2757809

Comment: thank you it worked